# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory"

Tags: java, android

I am facing following issue in android studio please help me

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
```

- with linked exception:

`[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/pkg.demo-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/pkg.demo-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]`

Comment: Do you have the jar `jaxb-impl-<version>.jar` in your classpath?

Comment: when i added jaxb-impl-2.2.6.jar its getting error.

Comment: 'Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/sun/xml/bind/Locatable.class'